# How can I get Thunderbird to trust a _non_ self-signed certificate for which I don't have the issuing CA?

Tags: email, security, thunderbird, ssl, certificate

A contact is trying to establish encrypted and signed communication with me using S/MIME.  She has a certificate from her organization, which was issued from a non-public CA.  It is *not* a self-signed certificate.  Unfortunately, I don't have that CA's certificate, so Thunderbird is reporting that her signatures are invalid.

How can I manually trust her email certificate without having the issuing CA in Thunderbird?